# box-shadow dont appear above a carousel

Tags: css, reactjs

hello i'm trying to put a boxshadow in my header, but for some reason my carousel is not letting my shadow box even appear in the div:

[image]

without my caroussel component:

[image]

code:

```
export default function App() {
  var settings = {
    dots: true,
    arrows: false,
    autoplay: true,

    draggable: false,
    infinite: true,
    slidesToShow: 1,
    slidesToScroll: 1
  };
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <div
        style={{
          width: "100%",
          position: "relative",
          height: "auto",
          position: "relative",
          boxShadow: " 3px 3px 3px #000",
          background: "green"
        }}
      >
        header
      </div>
  <Slider {...settings}>
    <div>
      <div style={{ background: "blue", height: "200px", width: "100%" }}>
        testing
      </div>
    </div>
  </Slider>
    </div>
  );
}
```

example:

https://codesandbox.io/s/flamboyant-allen-nr3t0

Comment: Your carousel is rendered after the header, so it is on a higher "layer" than the header and will cover the header if rendered in the same position. Your carousel is rendered below the header, but there is no margin, so it covers the area directly below the header which is where the box shadow is. You need to apply a margin to the bottom of your header. Try "marginBottom: 8px".

Comment: but I know that using position relative in my header it was to show my boxshadow, but for some css configuration in my slider it does not appear ..

Comment: If I create a div with a color it will appear.

Comment: You can try changing the zIndex css property to move your header to a higher layer than your carousel.

Comment: An alternative is to set the box shadow on the slider instead with `boxShadow: "inset 0px 3px 3px #000",`

Comment: @JMadelaine really z-index worked, but I still think that there is some css property of my slider that is disturbing my boxshadow

Comment: thanks SwimmerF and JMadelaine Awaited the response of one of the two to vote as the correct answer
both worked